# The meaning of "if that's what it takes"

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

I have watched a movie named [To All The Boys I've Loved Before]
and there's a conversation in the movie:

> (1). A: If you had a boyfriend, maybe you wouldn't have to drive at all, 'cause he would take us places.
>
> (2). B: If that's what it takes, I think you're stuck with me.

I want to know what the sentence(2) means, especially the meaning of "if that's what it takes"
, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

B is saying that if getting a boyfriend is what is necessary for her not to have to drive, then that is (probably) not going to happen, and so A will still have to ride with B.

"If that's what it takes" means "if that is what is necessary."